# Observable polling in RxJs 6

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

Just wanted to migrate some of my legacy code to a newer version of RxJs. The code was used for polling:

```
Observable
  .interval(5000)
  .startWith(0)
  .switchMap(() => this.apiService.getData())
  .subscribe(data => /* ... */)
```

This worked fine in RxJs `5.2.0`.

In RxJs `6.0.0` this doesn't work for multiple reasons (`Observable` only method is `create`, `interval` seems to be static, no method chaining, ...).

How to do this in latest RxJs?

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did not run it:

```
interval(5000).pipe(
    switchMap(() => this.apiService.getData())
).subscribe(data => /* ... */)
```

`Interval` is now a function that returns an Observable and transformations are chained inside `pipe` function.

Answer (score 1):

Referencing [LeeCampbell's RxCookbook](https://github.com/LeeCampbell/RxCookbook/blob/master/Repository/Polling.md) about reactive programming. Using interval is actually not practical. Because if you don't get a response from `this.apiService.getData()` in the interval value another value will be emitted by the interval and a new request is performed.

What you need to do is use a timer that emits a single value, use a switchMap to perform your request, and a repeat to poll again after success. Also, you can use a retry before the repeat if you want to retry after errors.

This is the implementation in C# using Rx.Net ([Ref](https://github.com/LeeCampbell/RxCookbook/blob/master/Repository/Polling.md#fault-tolerant)) :

```
public static IObservable<T> Poll<T>(this IObservable<T> request, TimeSpan period, IScheduler scheduler)
{
    return Observable.Timer(period, scheduler)
      .SelectMany(_ => request)
      .Retry()    //Loop on errors
      .Repeat();  //Loop on success
}
```

Which can be translated to RxJS 6 as following:

```
timer(5000).pipe(
    switchMap(tick => this.apiService.getData()),
    retry(3), // retry 3 times before bubbling an error
    repeat()
);
```

Further enhancements can be found in the [LeeCampbell's RxCookbook](https://github.com/LeeCampbell/RxCookbook/blob/master/Repository/Polling.md) .